# How to run smoothly the progress bar line in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var counter = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 60) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 1; 
      elem.innerHTML = counter++;
      elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0</div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

In the above snippet there is progressive bar which will fill automatically when the button is clicked and it will fill the bar by adding the style.width by `1`. I want that progressive bar to fill smoothly but the milliseconds shall remain unchanged i.e 1000 .

Comment: What do you mean by smoothly?using transition?

Answer (score 0):

Add `transition:width 600ms linear;` to

```
#myBar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition:width 600ms linear;
}
```

This will smoothly animate the width of the bar.

Note:Keep the transition timing equal to setInterval timeout to avoid jerky animation

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var counter = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 60) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 1; 
      elem.innerHTML = counter++;
      elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition:width 1000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

The transition in CSS makes smooth interpolation between 2 values. 
That means when you increment the width by 1px, the browser will increase the width by animating it, This takes place only after the javascript code to increase width is executed.

Comment: is this progress bar increase by one second? means that when there one second then it will increase?

Comment: @meena, if this answer helped you, then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit that you can render is a pixel.
What you can do is check for a certain inverval to increase the width. In the sample below I increase the width by 10px so that you can see the `transition` properly

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 600);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 60) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      counter++
      console.log(counter);
      if(counter % 5 == 0)
      {
        width += 10; 
        elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#myBar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;      
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about tweaking the JavaScript code to achieve the desired result:

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 0.5;
  // change the milliseconds to 10 or 5 to fill it relatively faster
  var id = setInterval(frame, 20);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 120) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 0.5;
      elem.style.width = width + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: is this progress bar increase by one second? means that when there one second then it will increase?

Comment: @meena No, it increases by 20 milliseconds which is equivalent to 0.02 seconds. So the function runs every 0.02 seconds.

Comment: I want to run it by one second means 1000 after 1000 milisecond

Comment: Do you wish to change the width too? Or it shall be the same as given in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trasition` and decrease the interval time

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 2;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 60) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 2; 
      elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: please see my snippet again you will understand

Comment: You need to decrease the `setInterval` milliseconds because with 1000 milliseconds, width increase after 1 second so that there is stop for 1 second